# psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-9.6

i have installed Postgresql and struggling to configure it, tried reinstalling but still facing issue, i removed all the files and then installed postgre 9.6 version, but getting below issues.

```
9.6 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

When i try to run postgre by using sudo -u postgres psql it gives below output

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

i have tried from other questions as well but can't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your PostgreSQL client is configured with a different socket directory (`/var/run/postgresql`) than your server. Check the `unix_socket_directories` configuration parameter in `postgresql.conf`.

Chances are that the server is listening on the default dirextory `/tmp`. Try

```sh
psql -h /tmp ...
```

Of course it could also be that the server is listening on a different port, e.g. 5555 (configuration parameter `port`). Then run

```sh
psql -p 5555 ...
```